# Get original source content for normal html element

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I have the code

```
<template id="tpl">
    {{# if (a && b) }} <h1>content</h1> {{/if}}
</template>
```

I want to get the source code via javascript.

---

but if I call

```
document.getElementById('tpl').innerHTML;
// return "{{# if (a &amp;&amp; b) }} <h1> content </h1> {{/if}}"
```

It parsed the `&` symbol.

---

or call

```
document.getElementById('tpl').content.textContent
// return "{{# if (a && b) }} content {{/if}}"
```

it only give text without `<h1>` tag.

---

both of results are not correct. Are there any way to get *original source text* as below:

```
{{# if (a && b) }} <h1>content</h1> {{/if}}
```

---

I know I can revert `&amp;` to `&`, or use `<script type="text/xxxx"></script>` to save text without parsing, or use `ajax` to re-call this page to get content.

But I am wondering if I can have a better way to get the source text directly from `<template>` tag.

Thanks your help.

Comment: The template element is supposed to contain document fragments, the content should be HTML, not template languages. Use a `<script>` instead (or put an HTML template in there and manipulate it with JS/DOM)

Answer (score -1):

With jquery you can try this

```
$('<textarea/>').html( $('#tpl').html() ).text();
```

Comment: hi, it's not work on the other case like: `<template id="tpl"> <table>{{#each(obj)}} <tr><td></td></tr> {{/each}} </table> </template>`